# Public Pinning is iOS Not working with Almofire

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, public-key-pinning

HI I wanted to implement the SSL pinning using public keys & I'm using Alamofire 4.8.2
Below is the code for that

```
func testWithAlmofire(){
    
    let serverTrustPolicies:[String:ServerTrustPolicy] = [
        "example.com": .pinPublicKeys(publicKeys: ServerTrustPolicy.publicKeys(), validateCertificateChain: true, validateHost: true)
    ]
    
    sessionManager = SessionManager(
     serverTrustPolicyManager: ServerTrustPolicyManager(policies: serverTrustPolicies)
    )
    
    
    sessionManager.request("https://example.com").response{ res in
        if res.response != nil{
            self.displayAlert(withTitle: "Test Result",
                               message: "Pinning validation succeeded")
        }else{
            self.displayAlert(withTitle: "Test Result",
            message: "Pinning validation Failed")
        }
        
    }
}
```

Please help me if I'm doing anything wrong.

Comment: I'm failed many times with alamofire but when I tried with same code after including the certificate in Application bundle then it is working . So I've a question here : Is is required to include the certificate  in Application bundle While using Public key pinning with Alamofire ?

Comment: Did you figure out how to implement public key pinning?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using something like that, I hope this helps

```
class NetworkingManager {
static let shared = NetworkingManager()

private init() {
    sharedSession = enableCertificatePinning()
}

var sharedSession: Session?

func enableCertificatePinning() -> Session {
    func getCertificates() -> [SecCertificate] {
        let certs = ["AmazonExample1", "AmazonExample2"]
        var certificates = [SecCertificate]()
        certs.forEach { cert in
            let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: cert, withExtension: "cer")!
            let localCertificate = try! Data(contentsOf: url) as CFData
            if let certificate = SecCertificateCreateWithData(nil, localCertificate) {
                certificates.append(certificate)
            }
        }
        return certificates
    }
    
    let certificates: [SecCertificate] = getCertificates()
    let trustPolicy = PinnedCertificatesTrustEvaluator(
        certificates: certificates,
        validateHost: true)
    let trustPolicies = [certificateUrl: trustPolicy,
                         "https://example.com": trustPolicy,
                         "https://example2.com": trustPolicy]
    let policyManager = ServerTrustManager(evaluators: trustPolicies)
    return Session(
        configuration: .default,
        serverTrustManager: policyManager)
}
}
```

You can use like that

```
func exampleRequisiton(someBody: exampleBody,  completion: @escaping (Result<responseExample, NetworkErrors>, _ message: String?) -> Void){

guard let url = URL(string: InviteUrl) else {
    completion(.failure(.invalidUrl), nil)
    return
}

var request = getDefaultRequest(url, .post)
request.httpBody = try? JSONEncoder().encode(someBody)

NetworkingManager.shared.sharedSession?.request(request).validate().responseDecodable(of: DefaultResponse.self, decoder: defaultDecoder) { data in

    switch data.result {
    case let .success(data):
            completion(.success(data), nil)
    case let .failure(error):
        completion(.failure(.genericError), nil)
    }
}
}
```

I tried to use an example with all options used in a requisition(body, header) because I think you gonna need to use this in some moment. the code bellow is those objects used in every requisition that I create separately

```
var HttpHeaders: HTTPHeaders {
let version = Bundle.main.infoDictionary?["CFBundleVersion"] as? String ?? ""
return [
    "SomeHeader if you have": "example"
]
}

func getDefaultRequest(_ url:URL, _ method:HTTPMethod) -> URLRequest{
var request = URLRequest(url: url)
request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
request.httpMethod = method.rawValue
request.headers    = HttpHeaders
return request
}

enum NetworkErrors: Error {
case authError
case genericError
case invalidUrl
case serverMessage
}

struct responseExample:Codable{
let systemTimeMillis: Int?
let message: String?
let status: Int?
}

struct exampleBody: Codable {
var example: String
}
```

Comment: HI @bruno great answer by your  but you are using certificate pinning and I'm using public key pinning . If you implemented somewhere using the public key then please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I spent hours to check the issue in my side.
I believe your serverTrustPolicy is correct.
However, there is some additional checks you should do :

- Verify that you have retrieved a valid certificate of the server.
  As long as you keep theses two on true : `validateCertificateChain: true, validateHost: true`
- The certificate must be in a der format (binary format). The pem format (Base64 format) will not work.
- The certificate is added on your project target resource files.